# When play framework create new instance of controller?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework, controller, akka

My code in play framework

```
public class MyController extends Controller {
    @Inject
    private final MyService myService;

    public Result myRequest(Http.Request request) throws InterruptedException {
        logger.info("Controler id {}", System.identityHashCode(this));
        myService.assignTemp();
        return ok();
    }
}
```

```
public class MyService {
    String temp = "temp";

    public void assignTemp() throws InterruptedException {
        temp = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        logger.info("I generate {}", temp);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        logger.info("I return {}", temp);
    }
}
```

when I call 4 request in same time. this is my log

```
2020-08-07 09:44:43 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15 - Controler id 1342212114
2020-08-07 09:44:43 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15 - I generate 45d596ca-40bc-4bbd-8d2d-494b49142133
2020-08-07 09:44:44 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17 - Controler id 1342212114
2020-08-07 09:44:44 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17 - I generate 8ec9ebf0-1571-4e03-b7b8-1f4dc2fcba67
2020-08-07 09:44:45 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16 - Controler id 1342212114
2020-08-07 09:44:45 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16 - I generate fe47949e-f8f9-44d1-8a40-f808be3b9f5d
2020-08-07 09:44:45 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15 - I return fe47949e-f8f9-44d1-8a40-f808be3b9f5d
2020-08-07 09:44:45 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22 - Controler id 1342212114
2020-08-07 09:44:45 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22 - I generate e15cb14c-9122-43a0-b024-1615655812cb
2020-08-07 09:44:46 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17 - I return e15cb14c-9122-43a0-b024-1615655812cb
2020-08-07 09:44:47 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16 - I return e15cb14c-9122-43a0-b024-1615655812cb
2020-08-07 09:44:47 +0700 [INFO] application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22 - I return e15cb14c-9122-43a0-b024-1615655812cb
```

Play use same instance of **MyController** for four threads. That make lots of **inject component** become non thread safe

I am looking for an answer of **when play framework create new instance of controller?** . or Play use same instance for any request

This is [Play document](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaActions#Controllers) about controller

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It creates an instance of the controller at startup and then uses the same instance for all requests.

(Assuming you're using the standard Play setup that uses Guice).